# Test axiom in PDL

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Wikipedia says the axiom for test in PDL is
$$
\langle \psi ? \rangle \phi \leftrightarrow \psi \wedge \phi,
$$
but why is this right? (i.e. what does it say?) And what is the corresponding relation $R_{\psi ?}$ on a (regular) frame?

Given an atom $A$, can we say $\langle \psi ? \rangle \phi \in A$ iff $\psi \in A$ and $\phi \in A$?

I know that equivalently one can state the axiom as $[\psi ?]\phi \leftrightarrow (\psi \to \phi)$, implied by $[\psi]\phi \leftrightarrow \neg \langle \psi \rangle \neg\phi$.

NB: the question marks at the and of sentences are real question marks, those inside brackets are test functions.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, the axiom says, that $(M,s) \models \langle ?\psi \rangle \varphi$ iff $(M,t) \models \psi$ and $(M,t) \models \varphi$. The result of an execution of a test $?\psi$ is a set $\{(s,s) \mid (M,s) \models \psi\}$, i.e. the set of states of the model $M$ in which $\psi$ holds, and the relation is reflexive. So, according to the axiom, $\langle ?\psi \rangle \varphi$ leaves only such states where **both** $\psi$ and $\varphi$ hold.